# Can we use Pthread_cond_signal() between between a thread and a child of same parent?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a parent  process and I have created a new thread from the parent process using `pthread_create()`. I have also created a child  process 'C' from the parent Process  using `fork()` and exited the parent process. Now the child is running as daemon.

Can I use `pthread_cond_signal` between child process and the thread? Or can `pthread_cond_signal` be used only between threads of the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition variables across processes if you make the condition variable process-shared, using condition variable attribute configured with the [`pthread_condattr_setpshared`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_condattr_getpshared.3p.html) function and a value of `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.  You will also have to make the associated mutex process-shared, using a mutex attribute configured with [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.3p.html).

By default, condition variables and mutexes cannot be shared across processes.